# Coldfusion - converting quote to plain text in string

Tags: coldfusion

I have users entering in strings into a form where the quotes are coming through as ‘ (or something similar, as if copied and pasted from somewhere else). Is there some Coldfusion code I can run on the string to replace any 'fancy quotes' with the plain text version? eg: turn ‘ into '

Comment: First things first: why do you need to do this? Secondly: you also need to throw us a bone a bit. Don't describe the text you need to modify, _actually include it in your question_. We can't guess what "‘ (or something similar...") might mean. What have you tried? You're basically asking how to do a find and replace, which is done with `replace` (look it up in the docs), but it sounds from your comments below you are not giving us all the relevant information about yer situation. It's easier to help you if you are precise about the situation.

Comment: My apologies - I'll try to clarify. I have a form on my website where users input data (and it gets stored in a nvarchar field in DB). However I've noticed some 'fancy quotes' (for lack of a better word) coming through in the form and these cause problems when I'm using the data elsewhere. I need all the quotes to be converted and stored as standard, plain text quotes.

Comment: @AdamCameron Here's what I've tested so far: `
<form action="test.cfm" method="post">
 
 
  
  <input type="text" name="thename"><input type="submit" value="Testing">
 
 
 </form>
 
 
 
 <cfif isDefined("Form.thename")>
 
 
 <cfoutput>
  
 Original: <input type="text" value="#Form.thename#">
  
  
 
  Fixed:  <input type="text" value="#Replace(Form.thename,"‘", "'", "all")#">
  
  
  
  
  
 </cfoutput> 
 </cfif>
`

Comment: Put the updates *in the question* please. Not as a comment.

Comment: Again, can you please be more clear than "'fancy quotes' (for lack of a better word)". **what exact actual characters are they**. Like their unicode characters / codes. IE: find out, tell us. You've given us some code above - good start - but you've not given us sample data. Equally, unless you know better, the fact it's coming from a form submission is neither here nor there: the problem is replacing x with y. Write some code that does that. Include the code in your Q. Explain how it's not working. Don't _describe_ stuff: _Show us_. A stand-alone/runnable version on trycf.com would be best

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rereplace](https://cfdocs.org/rereplace).

```
var test = "This has a fancy quote  ‘";
var without_special_quotes = test.reReplace( "‘|’", "'", "all" );

// should display false
writeOutput( without_special_quotes == test );
```

Comment: But won't that just find an instance of that particular fancy quote in that particular font? Is there a way to replace any non-plain text quote with a plain text quote?

Comment: No, the font that it is in won't matter. The search is done using the character code. You will need to create the regex that will work for your needs and pass it in as the first argument.

Comment: Why would one use `reReplace` here rather than just `replace`. You're just replacing one string literal with another string literal??

Comment: I've tried this code and it doesn't work... I just get the same string returned back to me

Comment: Yer going to need to give us more to go on, @CraigWalters: ie: "show us yer code". Because that code Etchesketch included does exactly what they claim, so clearly the code *you* are running is not that code. Working repro that does what one expects it to: https://trycf.com/gist/7abf62006d11925c1d046ee89eff9bdc/acf2021?theme=monokai. Update the question to show what you've tried, what you've researched, etc.

Comment: @etchesketch For me, this produces the same string:
`<cfoutput>`
`<cfset testString = "bob‘s burgers>`
`#Replace(testString ,"‘", "'", "all")#`
`</cfoutput>`

Comment: @AdamCameron I figured a regex would be more appropriate if there were more quote-like characters that needed to be replaced. I've updated my answer to demonstrate a better regex.

Comment: @CraigWalters the output may look the same depending on your font but the underlying characters should be different. I added a comparison that should show the variables are different after the replace.